# Wordpress - How to get any type posts include attachments by ids?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get any posts by an id list ($id_list), here is my codes

```
query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>-1,
               'caller_get_posts'=>1,
               'post_type'=>'any',
               'post__in'=>$id_list)
           );
```

i got posts and pages by this query, but attachments don't get included, i found they are filtered by 'post_type=any' which actually doesn't include attachment.

How do i get them all without have to do an extra query?

Comment: Are you sure? I was under the impression that post_type=any should include all post types except revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this took forever to figure out. It turns out that `post_type` can handle an array, which you will need to force it to fetch attachments. You also need to set `post_status` to an array to get it to grab the attachments, which usually have a status of 'inherit'. It seems some of them have post_status='closed', but I didn't dig into what that meant too much.

Here's my query which fetches posts and attachments:

```
<?php    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array(
            'attachment',
            'post',
        ),
        'post_status' => array(
            'open',
            'inherit',
        ),
        'numberposts' => '900',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    print_r($posts);
?>
```

EDIT: It should work fine with the loop you were using as well. I just used get_posts because it was easier to print it all out.

Comment: All about 'post_status' has a default value while attchment no 'post_status', i added 'post_status'=>array(null, 'publish') and my query works now.